# Perl Chat server client hangs up

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a chat server program in perl where the client enters some text and the server responds back with the sum of the ASCII value of the input. However, there is one problem. The server is processing the data right but the client is not receiving it. Here is the code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#client.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
$| = 1;

print "Client Program\n";

my $lp = 12000;

my $client_socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',
PeerPort => $lp,
Proto => 'tcp'
) or die "Cannot create the socket: $!\n";

print "Server connected at port $lp \n";
print "Enter the text to sent to the server: \n";
my $user_input = <>;
chomp $user_input;
print $client_socket;
$client_socket->send($user_input);
my $server_output;
$client_socket->recv($server_output, 1024);
print "ASCII Sum received: scalar(<$client_socket>)";
$client_socket->close();
```

The client just hangs up after sending the data (I can say that because I see the text received in the server program. However, the server processing doesn't show up until I terminate the client). I am not getting what is going wrong here. I can post the server program too but nothing seems to be wrong with it.

Here is the server program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#server.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
$| = 1;

print "Server Program\n";
my $lp = 12000;

my $server_socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
LocalPort => $lp,
Proto => 'tcp',
Listen => SOMAXCONN,
Reuse => 1) or die "Cannot create the socket: $!\n";
my $sum_ASCII = 0;
print "Server started at port $lp \n";
print "Press Ctrl+C to stop the server\n";
print "Waiting for client to connect.. \n";
# or die sprintf "ERROR:(%d)(%s)(%d)(+%s)", $!,$!,$^E,$^E
while (my $new_client = $server_socket->accept()) { 

my $addr = $new_client->peerhost();
my $port = $new_client->peerport();
print "Connected to client at $addr at port $port ";
while(<$new_client>) {
    print "Following is the text entered by client: \n";
    print "$_ \n";
    my $len = length($_);
    print "The length of the string is: $len\n";
    my @char_array = split(//);
    #print "@char_array";
    print "Initially sum is $sum_ASCII\n";
    for (my $i = 0; $i< $len; $i++)
    {
        print "Adding ASCII of '$char_array[$i]'.. ";
        $sum_ASCII = $sum_ASCII + ord($char_array[$i]);
        print "\t Sum = $sum_ASCII\n";
    }
    print "\n\nTotal sum of ASCII values of the all the sent characters is: $sum_ASCII\n"       
}
print "Sending the sum to the client.. \n";

my $np = 98765;
my $client_socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',
PeerPort => $np,
Proto => 'tcp'
) or die "Cannot create the socket: $!\n";
print "Client connected at port $np \n";
$client_socket->send($sum_ASCII);
$client_socket->close();

print "\nClient now disconnecting..\n";
close $new_client;  
print "\nWaiting for new client to connect.. \n";
```

}

```
#my $np = 12345
#my $client_socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
#LocalAddr => '127.0.0.1',
#PeerPort => $np,
#Proto => 'tcp'
#) or die "Cannot create the socket: $!\n";

#print "Client connected at port $np \n";

#$client_socket->send($sum_ASCII);
#$client_socket->close();
#print "Enter the text to sent to the server: \n";
#my $user_input = <>;
#chomp $user_input;
#print $client_socket;
#$new_client->send($sum_ASCII);

$server_socket->close();
```

Comment: posting the server program you are currently using would allow others to duplicate the problem (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is the same as in [Error in perl chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14250886/1741542), then your server waits for a newline, which is never sent.

Either skip `chomp $user_input;` in your client or read the data with

```
my $data;
my $retval = $new_client->recv($data, 1024);
print "Following is the text entered by client: $data\n";
$new_client->send($data);
```

in your server instead.

See [`recv`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/recv.html) for a description of the return value.

In your client you must change the output to

```
my $server_output;
$client_socket->recv($server_output, 1024);
print "ASCII Sum received: $server_output\n";
```

Comment: Ya, the server is the same and I tried it but that doesn't seems to work either. I made some changes which makes it work (partially). I created a new socket for listening. This helps but the code still doesn't print the ASCII value. The changes I made are:

`my $client_socket_new = new IO::Socket::INET (`
`PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',`
`PeerPort => $lp,`
`Proto => 'tcp',`
`Listen => SOMAXCONN`
`) or die "Cannot create the socket: $!\n";`
`print "\nText received from the server the server: \n";`
`my $retVal = $client_socket_new->recv($serverOutput,1024);`
`print "ASCII Sum received is $retVal \n";`

Comment: With the help of your modified answer its printing "ASCII Sum received: ". That's it. I mean I am not getting any the value of "$server_output"

Comment: @cool_sops Have you changed the server.pl as well? Because with both modifications, I get a complete round trip from client to server and back again.

Comment: I tried doing it. However, i am sending $sum_ASCII instead of $data which you have mentioned. I still get the same result as "ASCII Sum received: "

Comment: @"Olaf Dietsche" Can we chat over this?

Comment: @cool_sops I created a chat room at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22537/perl-chat-server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Socket workings in Perl.
But looking in your code I can suggest some changes.

Change your:

```
 print "ASCII Sum received: scalar(<$client_socket>)";
```

to:

```
   print "ASCII Sum received: " . scalar(<$client_socket>);
```

Hope this may print your log.

Comment: add "<" and ">" in quotes and then run the code.
I mean like 
print "ASCII Sum received: <" . scalar($client_socket>) . ">";

Comment: Try adding conditions to check whether $client_socket->recv($server_output, 1024); is defined or not.
I mean, is it undef or has some value.

Comment: If nothing works, finally try debugging your Perl code using perl's debugger. Check [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)

Comment: No, this doesn't help either. Actually writing scalar outside the quotes is giving an error. Also, I tried changed the print statement to following:

    print "ASCII Sum received: $server_output";

Its not giving any error, but its stops before the recv statement. Probably there is something wrong with the recv statement.

Comment: Did you try running your perl script like this: perl -d my_script.pl  ?

Comment: i tried just now. I still fails. I got the following output:

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'perldoc perldebug' for more help.

syntax error at Client.pl line 35, near ">) "
Execution of Client.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
 at Client.pl line 37.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22532/discussion-between-cool-sops-and-krishna)